# Fluent NHibernate and the repository pattern

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fluent-nhibernate, repository-pattern

Is [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20110503184234/http://blogs.hibernatingrhinos.com/nhibernate/archive/2008/10/08/the-repository-pattern.aspx) a good guide if I want to implement the repository pattern in my asp.net mvc application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mostly. I haven't read it fully, but I prefer [S#arp Architecture](http://www.sharparchitecture.net) idea of SaveOrUpdate (mapped from NHibernate) for entities, it's more convenient thant Add/Remove. But it may be just personal preference. In any case you can look at S#arp for already implemented repositories over NHibernate/FluentNHiberate.

Comment: I'm having a problem with the vs template and you might know what's the problem. I have windows 7, visual studio 2008, t4 toolbox and the template installed in the correct place but i get an error that looks like this http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/1495742/Untitled-1.png

Comment: Does this help? http://sharparchitecture.codeplex.com/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=6969